# Confused between different form of Bellman equations mentioned in different literatures

Tags: optimization, recursion, machine-learning, dynamic-programming

I'm studying reinforcement learning from Prof. Andrew Ng's [lecture notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes12.pdf). Here the Bellman equation is mentioned as following:

$$V(s) = R(s) + \gamma\max_a\sum_{s'\in S}P(s'|s,a)V(s')$$

Note that in above equation, the state transition probabilities $P(s'|s,a)$ is not multiplied with the reward function $R(s)$ (which is instant reward).

Now in other reference like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370015/what-is-the-difference-between-value-iteration-and-policy-iteration) and [this](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa12/slides/mdps-exact-methods.pdf), the same Bellman equation is given in other form as following:

$$V(s) = \max_a \sum_{s'\in S} P(s'|s,a)[ R(s) + \gamma V(s')]$$

So what is the difference (intuitive) between above two equations? The first equation I mentioned above makes complete sense to me as explained the Andrew Ng's notes, but I don't understand why in second form of equation, we are multiplying transition probabilities with reward function $R(s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both are the same.

Start from the second equation
\begin{align*}
V(s) &= \max_a \sum_{s'\in S} P(s'|s,a)[ R(s) + \gamma V(s')] \\
&=\max_a \left( \sum_{s'\in S} P(s'|s,a) R(s) + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S}P(s'|s,a) V(s')] \right) \\
&=\max_a \left( R(s) \sum_{s'\in S} P(s'|s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S}P(s'|s,a) V(s')] \right) \\
&=\max_a \left( R(s) \cdot 1 + \gamma \sum_{s' \in S}P(s'|s,a) V(s')] \right) \\
&= \text{rhs of first equation}
\end{align*}

Comment: Right! Thanks for the answer! I derived till step 3 but I'm too stupid to see that summation of probabilities is 1. Thanks again and +1

Comment: Sorry, since the $\sum P(s'|s,a) = 1$， why we keep it one the second term, why this term isn't always a constant?

Comment: Because it is multiplied by a V(s') term.